# Can strong duality holds for convex programs, where Slater's condition is not satisfied?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, duality-theorems

I know that for a convex program, if Slater's condition is satisfied, then strong duality holds. I also know examples of convex programs, where Slater's condition is not satisfied and there is a positive duality gap. My question is: does there exist any convex program, which has zero duality gap but does not satisfy Slater's condition?

Comment: Well, there's all the other conditions on this list: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions#Regularity_conditions_(or_constraint_qualifications)

Answer (score 0):

The linear programing problem

$$\begin{array}{l l} 
\text{min }       & \ \ \  0 \\ 
\text{subject to } & \ \ \ x & \leq 0 \\
                   & -x & \leq 0 
\end{array}$$

satisfies your requirements.